# Issue using MIN() in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I made the following query that get the `MIN(id)` of duplicate `path` values in the table `movies`:

```
SELECT m.id, m.user_id , m.path
FROM movies m
  INNER JOIN (
               SELECT Min(id) as movie_id, path,  COUNT(*)
               FROM movies
               WHERE importer LIKE '%AS%'
               GROUP BY  path
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp
    ON  temp.path = p.path
        AND temp.movie_id = m.id
        AND importer LIKE '%AS%'
```

I got this result:

```
  id       | user_id |     path    | 
­­­­­­­­­­­­------------------------------------
 2         | 1234    |     XXXX    |  
 8         | 4231    |     BBBB    |
```

The problem is that I have another movie with the same path but dont appear because the `MIN()` and the `GROUP BY path`

I want to group the path but dont exlude the other path because I do `MIN(id)`

This is the expected result:

```
  id       | user_id |     path    | 
­­­­­­­­­­­­------------------------------------
 2         | 1234    |     XXXX    |  
 8         | 4231    |     BBBB    | 
 5         | 3421    |     BBBB    |
```

What Im doing wrong?

`@Tim Biegeleisen`

The problem is with that query I obtain duplicated paths with same user_id :

```
  id       | user_id |     path    | 
­­­­­­­­­­­­------------------------------------
  3523        12287         asd
  3524        12287         asd
  3525        12287         asd
```

I should obtain the min id for each grouped path.

Comment: Surely you would want temp.importer to equal p.importer!! Beyond that, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: DISTINCT (user_id)?

Comment: Please show us sample data if possible.

Comment: @user3741598 Be aware that DISTINCT is not a function - it takes no arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to `GROUP BY` the `user_id` *and* `path`, and then choose the record having the smallest movie ID, should there be multiple users associated with a given `path`.  If so, then the following query should work:

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.user_id, m1.path
FROM movies m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, path, MIN(id) AS min_id
    FROM movies
    WHERE importer LIKE '%AS%'
    GROUP BY user_id, path
) m2
    ON m1.path    = m2.path AND
       m1.user_id = m2.user_id AND
       m1.id      = m2.min_id
```

Comment: @devtreat I updated my answer.  I think you want to `GROUP BY` the user ID and path, and then retain the record with the minimum ID.

Comment: This query made what I wanted. Thank you very much!